# How to set rightmost 8 bit of a 64bit int to a char var?

Tags: c

For example, I have a 64 bit var `a`, and a 8 bit char `b`

```
unsigned long long a = 0x1234567890123456;
unsigned char b = 0x78;
```

I want `a` to become 0x12345678901234**78**

I want rightmost 8 bit of `a` to set to `b`, and remain left 56 bits untouched, how can i do this?

```
a = a & (0xFFffFFffFFffFFff | b); //is this correct?
```

??

Comment: Do you mean `a = (a & 0xFFffFFffFFffFF00) | b;` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a useful macro defined in `limits.h` that can help make it portable. It's `CHAR_BIT`.

```
a = ((a >> CHAR_BIT) << CHAR_BIT) | b;
```

And that's it. The piece in parentheses clears the least significant `CHAR_BIT`s of `a`, and then that can be bitwise-ored with `b`.

Comment: maybe there should be a `b & 0xFF` to keep other things safe.

Comment: @TahaPaksu - Safe from what? The static type of `b` is already an unsigned char.

Comment: Yep, I didn't look at the type. Sorry.

Comment: isn't that b = ((a >> CHAR_BIT) << CHAR_BIT) | b; i mean the question is "set rightmost 8 bit of a 64bit int to a char var?"

Comment: @potato - The OP's own code sample assigns to `a`. I gathered that's what they wanted.

Comment: @StoryTeller its only a matter of applying correct logic OP should be able to get that

Comment: Will this change left 56 bits of a? I need left 56 bits remain unchanged

Comment: @Sato - It won't. So long as you make sure it shifts right first.

Comment: @StoryTeller oh, i need left 56 bits remain unchanged. only rightmost 8 bits set to `b`

Comment: @Sato - I gathered that. That's why I propsed a sòution that **will not** change them.

Comment: @StoryTeller which is?

Comment: @Sato - The one in my answer.

Comment: nice. #define CLEAR_RIGHT_X_BITS(a, x) ((a) = ((a >> (x)) << (x))) should do for x bits.